# Excel Web Query with the credentials , Error saying (404) Not found

Tags: excel, powerquery

1. I want to get the data into the web query from  url https://www.screener.in/screen.....all-stock/
2. This screen can be accessed with user is logged in
3. but when user is not logged in this screen cannot be accessed
4. I want to retrieve this data into the excel.
5. Added the following code in Advance Editor and authentication type as basic
6. Following error is thrown, attached in the xls
7. Any help in this regards is highly appreciated.

Comment: how can we add the xls file here ..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your sample data within your question - no upload needed. Please read [repro], this will help you to improve your question.